Create route and alternate route in QGIS shortest path
I am using shortest path to create the shortest route from a point layer of addresses to a particular point using a street line layer as the routing layer.  It all works very well.  What I would really like is to create the route and an alternative route to prove that there are multiple way to get to a particular place from a particular neighborhood.  Can anyone thing of a tool or way to do this?

What would be the criteria used to create the routes?
